# Prevent Xcode from jumping to debugging after crash

Tags: ios, xcode

Hey is there a way to prevent xcode from switching to the debug navigator every time an app crashes? I'd rather stay in the file I am working at a time, the "new" view is completely useless for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look under Preferences -> Behaviors in Xcode. I haven't actually tested this myself, but going to Running -> Pauses and unchecking to "Show navigator Debug navigator" and/or "Show debugger with Current Views" sounds like it should do what you want.

Alternately, you might want to play around with these settings to find something that suits you.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! Never clicked on this before and now I realized how many hours this could've saved me in the last couple of months.

Comment: @user2875404 Glad I could help! :D